# How to apply setTimeout function to delay bubbleSort algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, delay, settimeout

This is my code for bubble sort algorithm simulator. Algorithm works and prints output correctly. But I want to delay each step for 2 seconds and then display output. That means I want to delay each iteration of inner for loop of bubble sort. Thank you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
input[type=text], select {
    width: 60px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=button] {
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    width:500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
Canvas{
      padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    display: block; 
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;




}
#pp{
width:300px;
margin-left:3px;    

}
#alltext{
height:300px;
width:500px;    

}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3 align="center"style="text-decoration:underline">Algoritham Simulator</h3>

<div align="center">
  <form >
    <label >Insert Numbers     </label>
    <input id="pp" type="text"  >


    <input type="button" onClick="myMove()" value="Sort" >




  </form>

</div>

<canvas id="myCanvas" height="10000" width="900">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
var height1 = 10;
var height2 = 50;
var count =0;
 var canvas;
 var ctx;

function setCanvas(){

  canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.canvas.height =10000;
        ctx.canvas.width = 900;


}

function draw(cars,j){


        height1+=85;  
        height2+=85;
        count++;

        var rectSize = 80;
        var horizontalGap=1;



        for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++) {


            if(i==j || i==j+1){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle="green";
            ctx.fillRect((rectSize+horizontalGap),height1,rectSize,rectSize); 

            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
            }else{
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle="black";
            ctx.fillRect((rectSize+horizontalGap),height1,rectSize,rectSize); 
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
            }


            var text = cars[i];

            ctx.fillText(text, (rectSize+40)+horizontalGap ,height2);

            horizontalGap+=100;  


        }



}


function myMove() {
    setCanvas();
    var yourArray = [];
    var inputText = document.getElementById("pp").value;
    yourArray=inputText.split(",");


    bubbleSort(yourArray);
}


function bubbleSort(items) {
  var length = items.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { //Number of passes

   var c=0;
        for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) { //Notice that j < (length - i)
      //Compare the adjacent positions

     if(items[j] > items[j+1]) {
        //Swap the numbers
        var tmp = items[j];  //Temporary variable to hold the current number
        items[j] = items[j+1]; //Replace current number with adjacent number
        items[j+1] = tmp; //Replace adjacent number with current number
      }     
      }

  draw(items,j);     
  }

}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you. For example, what does ``CSS`` have to do with your question?

Comment: You might just consider to use setTimeout to invoke draw function

Answer (score 1):

You can't just pause a JS script, but you can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to queue up a function to be run after a given delay. Which means you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to build a sort of pseudo-loop with a delay for each iteration.

Following is a conversion of your original nested `for` loop function to work with `setTimeout()`.

I haven't tried to hook this into your existing `draw()` code that uses a canvas - to keep the code in the answer short I'm just calling my own simple `draw()` for demo purposes when you click "Run code snippet" - but it should give you the general idea. (For demo purposes I've used a much shorter delay than you asked for, but obviously you can change that.)

```js
function animatedBubbleSort(items, drawCallback) {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;
  var length = items.length;
  
  (function nextIteration() {
    if (j >= length - i - 1) {
      j = 0;
      i++;
    }
    if (i < length) {
      if (items[j] > items[j+1]) {
        // swap items
        var temp = items[j];
        items[j] = items[j+1];
        items[j+1] = temp;
        drawCallback(items, j+1);
      }
      j++;
      setTimeout(nextIteration, 100);
    } else // finished
      drawCallback(items);
  })(); 
}

var values = [13, 12, 1, 19, 20, 4, 6, 2, 18, 15, 3, 7, 14, 17, 5, 9, 16, 11, 8, 10];

animatedBubbleSort(values, function draw(items, j) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = items.map(function(v, i) { return i===j ? "<span>" + v + "</span>" : v; }).join(", ");
});
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```